# How do I reference a sheet name in vba where the name has a number different

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am trying to reference a range of sheets with a common name and a unique number using vba to claer a range on each sheet. But I get a 1004 error.

```
For lngWeek = 1 To 53
    strSheet = "Week" & Trim(Str(lngWeek))
    strRange = strSheet & "!B5:H7"
    Range(strRange).Activate
Next
```

The sheets are Week1, Week2, etc and I need to clear ranges B5:H7 on each sheet. All the way from Week1 to Week53.

Why does the Range.Activate fail to select each page?

Comment: You don't need to `Activate`. `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Week" & lngWeek).Range("B5:H7").ClearContents`.

Comment: Use CStr rather than Str.  Read the docs to find out why.

Comment: You don't even need `CStr`. [`&` forces string concatenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ampersand-operator).

Comment: No need for `CStr`, @BigBen, but "say what you mean and mean what you say" for greater clarity in code

Comment: @FreeMan `&` does what it says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to clear the same range in any worksheet with a name of the form "Week#", you can work through all sheets and only act on those with a name that matches the right format.

```
Sub ClearSpecial()
Dim ASheet As Worksheet
Dim ToClear As Boolean

For Each ASheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ToClear = Left(ASheet.Name, 4) = "Week" ' add more conditions if needed
    If ToClear Then
        ASheet.Range("B5:H7").ClearContents
    End If
Next ASheet

End Sub
```

If for example there if also a worksheet called "Weekly Summary" you could expand your test to exclude that also.

Comment: Thank you. I used this in the button code, It takes a while but works beautifully (there are 52 Weeks and 12 Month pages plus a few others).

Answer (score 5):

You are getting error 1004 here:

> ```
> Range(strRange).Activate
> ```

Because `strRange` is sheet-qualified, but `Range` isn't; it's an [implicit ActiveSheet reference](https://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ImplicitActiveSheetReference), which means the `Range.Activate` member call can only work when `strRange` is referring to a cell that's already on the `ActiveSheet`. Suggestion: rename `strRange` to `cellAddress` or something actually meaningful. "str"-for-String isn't useful; "oh that's an address" is ;-)

In order to be able to select a specific `Range`, you must first dereference the `Worksheet` object you mean to be working with - where `sheetName` contains the name of the worksheet:

```vb
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName)
```

And then the `strRange` address no longer needs the `WeekXX!` part:

```vb
ws.Activate
ws.Range("B5:H7").Select
```

Note that unless it's for the convenience of the user, there is usually little to no reason to ever `Select` or `Activate` anything in VBA: when you correctly qualify all objects you're working with, you will not be getting error 1004 when the `ActiveSheet` isn't the sheet your code assumes is active, because the code would no longer be assuming that a sheet is active.

Comment: Thank you Mathieu. I am old school and to me the variable type is also useful: "Oh that's and address" is not helpful as it could be a long number, short number, double number, string or many other variable types. I put the str in front to show that the Range variable is a string.
But thanks for clarifying the cause of the 1004 error.

Comment: @tmd63 if you say so. FYI Systems Hungarian Notation is universally dropped and heavily discouraged in every single typed programming language out there, and its stubborn deeply-rooted usage in VBA and VB6 is very much contributing to making VBA and VB6 the single most-dreaded language in existence. I'd warmly recommend reading [Making Wrong Code Look Wrong](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/), which explains how and why Hungarian Notation came to be, and how and why Hungarian Notation *done right* is not "str-for-string" or "lng-for-long" at all. Cheers!

Comment: Also Ctrl+i gives you the data type of anything the caret is on, FWIW, and no variable should be declared out of sight from its usage.

Comment: As tireless and almost missionary communicator of *basic* comprehension for often neglected or even ignored code *basics* you deserve *un grand merci*! - I'd truly hope that the essence of your valuable comments and [articles](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/) - could find expression in the *official help* sites where generations of users potentially are mislead because fully qualified range references seem to be widely unknown. @MathieuGuindon